# sql price between min and max

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, psql

okay i need help i'm trying to allow the user to enter min and max price then on submit it updates the records but at the momenets its displaying this. resource(3) of type (pgsql result)

the form

```
    <form action ="database_connect.php" method="post">
    Songs price min: <input action="database_connect.php" method="post" type="text" name="minimum">
  </br>
      Songs price max:<input action="database_connect.php" method="post" type="text" name="maximum">
      </br>
       <input type="submit" value="Sort">
         <?php
        echo ($_POST['check_list']);
          $min= "minimum";
       $max= "maximum";
      if (isset($_POST['check_list'])) { 
        echo $_POST['$min'];
      echo $_POST['$max'];
     }
        //error_reporting(~E_ALL);
       $conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432 dbname=teaching user=csguest password=r3p41r3d");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM music` WHERE price BETWEEN {$_POST['minimum']} AND        {$_POST['maximum']}";
    $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM music");
    var_dump($result)           
            ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: Start by removing the `method="post"` from your inputs. You also have a missing tick or one too many around your `music` table.

Comment: This `$result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM music");` should most likely need to be `$result = pg_query($query);` - then `$_POST['$min']` and `$_POST['$max']` should be `$min` and `$max`. You also don't have an element called/named "check_list". You need to get back to the 'ol drawing board.